# JS code to set li selected whose child's value is '100'

Tags: javascript

```
<li class="donation-amount suggested-donation-amount">
    <label for="recurring-form-5ae58b3275dc3-field-100">
           <input id="recurring-form-5ae58b3275dc3-field-100" type="radio" name="donation_amount" data-recurring="true" data-value="100" value="100">
           <span class="amount">$100.00 <span class="recurring-details"> / month</span></span>
           <span class="description"></span>
    </label>
</li>
```

There are few options for donation. I would like to make the one above as pre selected before someone selects something else. I am new in javascript so i worte this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('input[value="100"]').parent('li').addClass('selected');
</script>
```

I get Unexpected token when i run it in Console. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jQuery [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to find the `li`.

Also, don't forget to import jQuery before you use it :)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('input[value="100"]').closest('li').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="donation-amount suggested-donation-amount">
    <label for="recurring-form-5ae58b3275dc3-field-100">
           <input id="recurring-form-5ae58b3275dc3-field-100" type="radio" name="donation_amount" data-recurring="true" data-value="100" value="100">
           <span class="amount">$100.00 <span class="recurring-details"> / month</span></span>
           <span class="description"></span>
    </label>
</li>
```

**EDIT**

Here is a version without jQuery :

```
document.querySelector('input[value="100"]').closest('li').classList.add('selected');
```

That way you don't have to worry about importing jQuery.

```js
document.querySelector('input[value="100"]').closest('li').classList.add('selected');
```

```css
.selected{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="donation-amount suggested-donation-amount">
    <label for="recurring-form-5ae58b3275dc3-field-100">
           <input id="recurring-form-5ae58b3275dc3-field-100" type="radio" name="donation_amount" data-recurring="true" data-value="100" value="100">
           <span class="amount">$100.00 <span class="recurring-details"> / month</span></span>
           <span class="description"></span>
    </label>
</li>
```

Comment: While true, the `Unexpected token` indicates that the issue is elsewhere (not posted in OP's code so far)

Comment: Correct, let's wait for OP.

Comment: I am placing the code into the console screen in chrome inspect and tried every combinations and this is what i get:
$('input[value="100"]').closest('li').addClass('selected');
VM830:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
$('input[value="100"]').closest('li').addClass('selected');

</script>
VM832:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
$('input[value="100"]').closest('li').addClass('selected');
VM834:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @leahakbashev I added a version without jQuery, try it.

Comment: Thank you @Zenoo it worked in the console. However, when i place the following into the <head> it returns error:<script>
document.querySelector('input[value="100"]').closest('li').classList.add('selected');
</script>
(index):170 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closest' of null

Comment: @leahakbashev You need to wait for the page to load : `window.onload = function(){ document.querySelector('input[value="100"]').closest('li').classList.add('selected'); }`. Or to put the script at the very bottom of the `body`.

Comment: I placed it into the <body> and it worked. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, don't forget to validate the answer if it solved your issue.